# Jsoup combine multiple Evaluator

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this code:

```
Document dom = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

Evaluator aTag = new Evaluator.Tag("a");
Evaluator linkClass = new Evaluator.Class("foo");
Evaluator hrefContains = new Evaluator.AttributeWithValueContaining("href", "abc");
```

I know how to use one evaluator

```
dom.selectFirst(aLinkClass);
```

But I want to get the first element from `dom` which matches all 3 `Evaluator`s.

How can I apply multiple `Evaluator` in same select?

Comment: If it not already exists, you could write an own subclass of `Evaluator` that takes a list of other evaluators and does an AND or an OR operation on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the select method which accepts a string after parsing your evaluators to string and joining them with no delimiter for an AND link or a comma as delimiter for an OR link. Example:

```
Evaluator aTag         = new Evaluator.Tag("a");
Evaluator linkClass    = new Evaluator.Class("foo");
Evaluator hrefContains = new Evaluator.AttributeWithValueContaining("href", "abc");
    
String all_AND = String.join("",  aTag.toString(), linkClass.toString(), hrefContains.toString());
String all_OR  = String.join(",", aTag.toString(), linkClass.toString(), hrefContains.toString());
    
System.out.println(doc.selectFirst(all_AND).text());
```

Alternatively you could get all elments from your document and make the filtering on the java side yourself using for example a for loop or streams:

```
Evaluator all = new Evaluator.AllElements();
Optional<Element> target = doc.select(all)
                                .stream()
                                .filter(e -> e.is(aTag))
                                .filter(e -> e.is(linkClass))
                                .filter(e -> e.is(hrefContains))
                                .findFirst();
target.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```